# terraform doesn't load environment variables set in fish

Tags: environment-variables, terraform, fish, terraform-provider-aws

In the root folder of my project next to `main.tf`, I have a script called `load_env.fish` containing these two lines:

```
set -U AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE "~/path/to/file"
set -U AWS_PROFILE "my_profile"
```

I run that, then I run the command `terraform import foo bar`. It gives me `Access Denied`.

However, if I use bash instead of fish, and I set up the same environment variables, then `terraform import foo bar` works.

And I can even get it to work in fish if I do this:

1. from bash, set up environment variables
2. start the fish shell from bash
3. now in the fish shell, run `terraform import foo bar`

So,

Why does it work if I use bash and not fish? And why does it work in fish if the fish shell is opened from a bash shell that has the correct environment variables set?

How can I use `terraform` in the fish shell without having to open nested bash and fish shells?

Comment: What does `aws sts get-caller-identity` show when running from fish?

Answer (score 2):

[Universal variables](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_universal) are shared between all fish sessions, **but they are not automatically exported to subprocesses**.

I simply changed all instances of `set -U ...` to `set -Ux ...` and everything worked.

EDIT: After seeing [KurtisRader's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57889110/terraform-doesnt-load-environment-variables-set-in-fish/57890120#comment102205916_57890120) concerning the downside of `set -Ux` and reading a bit more, I realize now that fish has the `source` command just like bash. So, inside the script I can just use

```
set -x foo bar
```

Then I can

```
$ source load_env.fish
```

instead of just

```
$ ./load_env.fish
```

Comment: Exporting universal vars is almost always a bad idea. First, consider that when you change the var in shell #1 the change will be seen by shell #2 but it won't affect the value of the var inherited by any processes already started by either shell. Second, by making the var "universal" it means you can't change it in one shell session (e.g., to do an experiment) without affecting all your other shell sessions. **Don't export uvars.**